# How to select multiple files and directories with QML FileDialog

Tags: qt, qml

I'm begining with Qt 5.5.
I want to use QML as much as possible for UI matters.
I need a file and directory picker that can select multiple objects, either files or directories.
[`QFileDialog`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html) is able to do so, and according to [this solution](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/34226-QFileDialog-select-multiple-directories?p=220108#post220108), the `QFileDialog` needs to be set to non native.
According to [QML `FileDialog` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html), there's no way for the programmer to force the QML `FileDialog` object to be non native.

Must I use C++ to handle this or is there a way to access the properties of the QML `FileDialog` in order to force the instanciation of an underlying `QFileDialog`, and then a way to access to this instance properties from QML in order to implement the solution in QML ?

Comment: For selecting multiple files,  you could set  `FileDialog` 's `selectMultiple` property to true.  However, then according to the documentation, you can't select multiple directories.

Comment: @nfranklin, where does it say that?

Comment: Here under [the documentation for `selectFolder`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#selectFolder-prop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit #1:** see comments below. @SR_ is right. I think it's necessary to implement some code in C++ to get the expected behaviour.

**Edit #2:** my previous answer was wrong. Setting `selectMultiple` property as `true` is not a solution. So I've updated the answer to show a new proposal. See the comments below for more info about the discussion about this issue.

The next code is based on the Qt example [File System Browser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-filesystembrowser-example.html) and the code is [uploaded](https://github.com/ftena/qml-c/tree/master/file-browser) to GitHub.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include "filemanagement.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    FileManagement fileManagement;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QFileSystemModel *fsm = new QFileSystemModel(&engine);
    fsm->setRootPath(QDir::homePath());
    fsm->setResolveSymlinks(true);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("fileManagement", &fileManagement);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("fileSystemModel", fsm);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQml.Models 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("File System")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    Row {
        id: row
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 12
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        ExclusiveGroup {
            id: eg
        }

        Repeater {
            model: [ "None", "Single", "Extended", "Multi", "Contig."]
            Button {
                text: modelData
                exclusiveGroup: eg
                checkable: true
                checked: index === 1
                onClicked: view.selectionMode = index
            }
        }
    }

    ItemSelectionModel {
        id: sel
        model: fileSystemModel
        onSelectionChanged: {
            console.log("selected", selected)
            console.log("deselected", deselected)
            fileManagement.printFileNames(model, selectedIndexes)
        }
        onCurrentChanged: console.log("current", current)
    }

    TreeView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 2 * 12 + row.height
        model: fileSystemModel
        selection: sel

        onCurrentIndexChanged: console.log("current index", currentIndex)

        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Name"
            role: "fileName"
            resizable: true
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            title: "Permissions"
            role: "filePermissions"
            resizable: true
        }

        onClicked: {
            console.log("clicked", index)            
            fileManagement.printPath(index.model, index)
        }
        onDoubleClicked: isExpanded(index) ? collapse(index) : expand(index)
    }

    Component.onCompleted: fileManagement.test()
}
```

**filemanagement.h**

```
#ifndef FILEMANAGEMENT_H
#define FILEMANAGEMENT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFileSystemModel>

class FileManagement : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FileManagement(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE bool printPath(QFileSystemModel* fileSystemModel,
                               const QModelIndex &modelIndex);

    Q_INVOKABLE bool printFileNames(QFileSystemModel* fileSystemModel,
                                    QList<QModelIndex> modelIndexList);

signals:

public slots:

    void test() {
        qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot";
    }
};

#endif // FILEMANAGEMENT_H
```

**filemanagement.cpp**

```
#include "filemanagement.h"

FileManagement::FileManagement(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

bool FileManagement::printPath(QFileSystemModel* fileSystemModel,
                       const QModelIndex &modelIndex) {
    qDebug() << "+ File path: " << fileSystemModel->filePath(modelIndex);
    return true;
}

bool FileManagement::printFileNames(QFileSystemModel* fileSystemModel,
                            QList<QModelIndex> modelIndexList) {
    qDebug() << "+ " << modelIndexList.size() << " items selected: ";
    QList<QModelIndex>::iterator i;
    for (i = modelIndexList.begin(); i != modelIndexList.end(); ++i) {
        qDebug() << "++ File name: " << fileSystemModel->fileName(*i);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I've tested it and it does not work : you cannot select a directory (even though in some cases, it appears selected, look at the `fileUrls` value). According to the documentation, if `selectFolder` is `true` (it is `false` by default), `selectMultiple` must be `false`.

Comment: Oh, I see... You're right. Sorry. I will try to find a solution.

Comment: After some days of investigation, I think is not possible to select directories and files in the way you want to do it :( At least, using only QML. It's just an idea, but you could implement your own [File Browser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-filesystembrowser-example.html) integrated with C++ to manage the selections of files and directories. I have an [example](https://github.com/ftena/qml-c/tree/master/file-browser) in GitHub. The code should be short.

Comment: I guessed there might be and easy way to specialize the component behaviour in some way instead of writing something new, as you've done. Let's guess it's not that easy, and therefore necessitates to write a custom dialog. If you modify your answer to show your solution and keep a track of the wrong one, I'll accept it (it's not clear currently that your first solution does not work without reading comments).

Comment: @SR_ OK, no problem. In any case, I'm not just looking for the green mark ;) I'm trying to help :)